# Assign a color to a variable name in a newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, color, ifthenelse

I am writing a complex diagram using TikZ in which the colors used for certain nodes depend on the value of the input variable. I cannot use the color itself as an input variable as certain things other than a color also change.

I have not written this yet, so cannot provide a MWE, but the idea is:

1. Check the value of an input parameter (say #1) using \ifthenelse.
2. Assign some colors to a set of variable, say boxcolor=red!90!black,flatcolor=blue!30!green, juxtaposecolor=yellow if #1 takes one value, another set of the above colors if #1 takes another value.
3. Draw the diagram, using boxcolor, flatcolor, juxtaposecolor, etc. directly, and colors calculated based on them (boxcolor!40!flatcolor).

How do I do this inside a newcommand? Can color variables be first set in some way, and then used in some common code block that follows?

Comment: It would be useful for you to provide a minimum working example of how you would like to use these color assignments.  As to the test, if the comparison is a number, `\ifnum#1=<test value>\relax<one set of assignments>\else<other set of assignments>\fi`.  If `#1` is a string, not a number, a different syntax is needed.

Comment: What about these answers in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448333/154390) some goes according to what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the effect you want?
[image]

```tex
\documentclass[margin = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \def\test#1{%
  \ifnum#1>10 %
    \colorlet{main}{red}%
  \else
    \ifnum#1>1 %
      \colorlet{main}{blue}%
    \else 
      \colorlet{main}{brown}%
    \fi 
  \fi 
  }

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in{-1,5,12}
  {
    \test{\x}
    \draw[main] (\x,0)circle(2);
  }  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

when #1 > 10 , main = red;
and 1 < #1 <= 10, main = blue;
else, main = brown.

Comment: Indeed. \colorlet is exactly what I was looking for.